# How to time to date format

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm converting time to date format. The time is 14:23:00  and I need to convert it to 02:23 AM.i m able to convert. but it is also adding the default date on time. i m getting this Sat Jan  1 02:23:00 2000

> . I need only time. Please help me on this.

My code is :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[formatter setDateFormat : @"hh:mm a"];

NSString *stringTime = @"14:23:00";

NSDate *dateTime = [formatter dateFromString:stringTime];
 NSLog(@"Date is %@", dateTime);
```

Comment: Strictly spoken `13:23 PM` does not exist. There is `1:21 PM` (12 hour format) or `13:23` (24 hour format). But you are making a common mistake. You probably want to convert string -> date with the **input** format and convert it back with a different **output** format

Comment: means suppose 12:23 Pm then how it will work ?

Comment: i need this time to Mon time Nov 13 12:25:43 2017 to "12:25 PM " but "12:25 PM " should be on date format.

Comment: dont get it at all but there TONS of dateformatter questions here already.. one should have what you need

Answer (score 0):

An `NSDate` object contains both date and time and can't exist without both parts. That said, you don't have to use the entire thing. The bit you are missing is that you need *two* formatters. One to convert the input string to a date and one to convert the Date to the new output string. You only made the output formatter.

```
NSDateFormatter *input = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
[input setDateFormat : @"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDateFormatter *output = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
[output setDateFormat : @"hh:mm a"];

NSString *stringTime = @"14:23:00";

NSDate *dateTime = [input dateFromString:stringTime];
NSString *result = [output stringFromDate:dateTime];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: I already posted this same answer and since deleted it because it turns out this is not what the OP wants. Despite several requests (on my now deleted answer), the OP refuses to update their question to make their needs clear.